# XmlPullParser newPullParse thread safe

Tags: android, thread-safety, xmlpullparser

Why isn't the following code thread safe and how to fix it?

```
public abstract class BaseResponseHandler extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {
    private static XmlPullParserFactory xmlPullParserFactory;

    public static synchronized XmlPullParser newPullParser(String input) throws XmlPullParserException {
        if (xmlPullParserFactory == null) {
            xmlPullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        }

        final XmlPullParser parser = xmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(new StringReader(input));
        return parser;
    }
}
```

Comment: xmlPullParserFactory is not synchronized

Comment: and how can that code be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways:

1) Create multiple instances on every call. It is expensive but since it is not thread safe, this is one option

```
XmlPullParserFactory xmlPullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
final XmlPullParser parser = xmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser();
parser.setInput(new StringReader(input));
```

2) Create one instance and use it to create different parser each time under synchronization.

```
XmlPullParser parser = null;
synchronized(xmlPullParserFactory) {
   parser = xmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser();
}
```

Under heavy concurrency, option 1 is far faster than option 2. I recommend you to go with option 1.